# Como puedo retornar una respuesta con ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

resulta que intento producir un formulario con ajax, y que me envie una respuesta en caso de una serie de condiciones en php , inserto un registro pero siempre me indica que se produjo un error , siempre es 0 en vez de 1 Para que me diga el mensaje de exitoso , no entiendo el porque de esto , pongo codigo de ejemplo! :

```html
<form id="frmajax" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend><i class="zmdi zmdi-assignment-o"></i> &nbsp; Información del registro</legend>
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                            <label class="control-label">Materia del registro *</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="materia" required="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                            <label class="control-label">IDDOC *</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="iddoc" required="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <label>Documento del registro *</label>
                                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-raised btn-xs" type="file" name="file">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="variable" value="<?php echo $año ?>">
                                    <!-- Variable enviada de tipo hidden para identificar a que periodo guardar -->

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <p class="text-center" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <button id="btnguardar" class="btn btn-info btn-raised btn-sm"><i class="zmdi zmdi-floppy"></i> Guardar</button>
                        </p>
                    </form>
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnguardar').click(function() {
                var datos = $('#frmajax').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "agregar.php",
                    data: datos,
                    success: function(r) {
                        if (r == 1) {
                            alert("agregado con exito");
                        } else {
                            alert("Fallo el server");
                        }
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Envio esta informacion a un archivo php llamado agregar.php que tiene básicamente esto :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO daem2022(fecha_registro,materia,hora_registro,usuario,ruta,cod_doc)
VALUES ('$fecha_actual','$materia','$hora_actual','$usuario','$iddoc')";
echo mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Peros siempre me indica el valor negativo que es "Fallo en el server" , aunque me agrega el registro si , de antemano Muchas Gracias

Comment: y no has probado loguear a la consola el valor de r?